# Game crashes in IOS due to unsupported shaders

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, shader

I have built game from Unity to IOS. Everything is working fine in Unity. But when I export this game to IOS, the first two scenes loads very well, but when the gameplay scene is loaded from level manager, the scene causes the game to crash. :

[Here is screenshot for my logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDCop.png)

There is no error thrown by Xcode but the only warnings. I think these warning causes the game to crash.

```
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no 
vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default 
shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no 
vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to 
default shader.
```

I am using Unity 2017.1.1f1 with XCode 9.2. I have googled but didn't find any solution. Any help will be much appreciated...

Comment: This shouldn't be the cause of a crash, it most likely will just show your textures as a solid magenta colour or to whatever the default fallback shader is.. Have you tried looking at the logs that get made by your IOS device to see what happens when the game crashes?

Comment: Thank you for your response... When the game is running on debug mode, It doesn't even crashes. It only stuck when the button is pressed, that opens new scene. All the logs are shown in the image mentioned above in the post.

Comment: i agree that its probablynot the textures, but to clear that up try switching them to the mobile versions of their set ups available in the properties inspector for the textur/material. there you can select different shaders, some specced just for mobile

Comment: Hi Vanethrane, thank you for your response. I'll work on your suggestions...